# Assigning integers to strings

Tags: python, string, variables, integer

I'm working in Python and I have a list of integers: `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3]`.

I want to assign each integer a string as if it were a variable:
`['red', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow']`.

How would I go about doing this?

In that example, `1` corresponds to `'red'`, `2` corresponds to `'orange'`, and `3` corresponds to `'yellow'`.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to implement something like C enum in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
d = {1: 'red', 2: 'orange', 3: 'yellow'}
```

Then you can do this to change the list:

```
lst = [d[k] for k in lst]
```

The dictionary basically 'maps' objects (in this case integers) to other objects, which is just what you want.